# How can I limit the size of WriteStream buffer in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-management

I'm using a WriteStream in NodeJS to write several GB of data, and I've identified the write loop as eating up ~2GB of virtual memory during runtime (which is the GC'd about 30 seconds after the loop finishes). I'm wondering how I can limit the size of the buffer node is using when writing the stream so that Node doesn't use up so much memory during that part of the code.

I've reduced it to this trivial loop:

```
let ofd = fs.openSync(fn, 'w')
let ws = fs.createWriteStream('', { fd: ofd })
:
while { /*..write ~4GB of binary formatted 32bit floats and uint32s...*/ }
:
:
ws.end()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stream.write` function will return a boolean value which indicate if the internal buffer is full. The buffer size is controlled by the option `highWaterMark`. However, this option is a threshold instead of a hard limitation, which means you can still call `stream.write` even if the internal buffer is full, and the memory will be used continuously if you code like this.

```js
while (foo) {
    ws.write(bar);
}
```

In order to solve this issue, you have to handle the returned value `false` from the `ws.write` and waiting until the `drain` event of this stream is called like the following example.

```js
async function write() {
    while (foo) {
        if (!ws.write(bar)) {
            await new Promise(resolve => ws.once('drain', resolve));
        }
    }
}
```